# Capture key press on a page without input fields in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, key-events

I have an AngularJS application where I want to invoke a function when the user presses the Enter key while they are on the home page.

I know that AngularJS has ngEnter which can be used to submit a form when the Enter key is pressed, but in my case the operation is not a form submit. I just want to hide a section when user presses the Enter key.

How can I capture the key press event in the AngularJS controller, validate whether the key pressed is Enter key, then invoke a function?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, It will trigger every time you press a key on your page.

```
$document.bind('keyup', function (e) {
 $scope.myFunction (e.keyCode)
});

$scope.myFunction = function(keyVal) {
if (keyVal === 13)
 {
   //Do your stuff here
 }
}
```

May be it helps you, Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your controller.

```
// You can do this on any element by getting the element using document.querySelectorAll("#element_id")
        document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
            if(event.keyCode === 13){
                console.log('You pressed Enter key.');
                // do stuff here
            }
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ngkeyUp`.

For more read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup).

So basically you can use this:

```
input ng-keyup="event=$event">
```

to get the input and store the variable in a model and use it the way you want to.

You can also use `ngKeyPress`. Read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress).